# what's a good jquery-based content slider?

Tags: looking-for-a-script, javascript, jquery, css3

I've searched around there's so many but none seems to fit the requirements.

so here is what i'm looking for:
- needs to be lightweight (10+kb of JS just to slide images around is an overkill in my opinion and this is where most of the sliders fail at)
- not many effects are needed, simple slide or fade will do
- possible CSS3 support with fallback to jquery.animate would be a plus.
- it should let you put links on the images without having to use a caption

I tried nivoslider its too heavy, flexslider is 11kb minified javascript, anythingslider is 15kb minified, orbit is now part of foundation and the latest version is also too big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've tried the two most popular sliders around (Nivo <11k packed and Orbit <5k Packed), so there may not be anything else that is robust and suits your needs.

I've listed out some catalogs below and some ideas for places to look at that might be helpful below.

- Have a look at this it may help [180 Awesome jQuery Slider and
  Effects Roundup](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/01/jquery-slider.html)
- Take a tour through the templates at [theme forest](http://www.themeforest.com), there may be a suitable slider in one of the live demos.
- [60+ Useful jQuery Image Slider Roundup](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/01/jquery-image-slider.html)
- http://plugins.jquery.com/ (down at the moment but will hopefully be back online soon).

Comment: going through themeforest sounds like a good idea. i think i'll end up using flexslider. i already use jquery.animate.enhanced on the same page which means any jquery animation gets automatically converted to css3 when possible which covers the hardware acceleration issue.. i'll just have to live with the 11kb of code

Comment: -1 The request was for a recommendation. This is a pile of catalogs.

Comment: @Su' Thanks for the passive aggressive. There is no canonical answer to the question, my answer was that if you're not happy with Nivo (11k packed) and Orbit (<5k Packed) then there isn't much else out there robust so there may not be anything. Followed by some helpful advice for having a look around.

Comment: @Su' Not for nothing but this kind of snippyness is one of the reasons we're not getting much traction with users.

Answer (score 3):

[SlidesJS](http://slidesjs.com/) is less than 7kb minified and works pretty well.  It does simple slide and supports links.  Not sure about the CSS3/Animate requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You can download a zip with a demo [here](http://www.pritaeas.net/view/articles/portfolio-with-jquery). It just fades from one to the next. No documentation, just code (less than 1Kb).

This link and demo is from my personal (non-commercial) website.

Comment: Edit to [provide disclosure](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion), please. I'll reverse the downvote once done.

Comment: Changed as requested.